# Weka - How to remove an attribute whose all values are missing?

Tags: weka, apriori

I have a CSV file containing data for a market-basket analysis. I have imported the file successfully to Weka, but I found that some attributes does not have any value, i.e., all values are missing. Weka don't let me use the Apriori algorithm with this data, so I would like to know if there is a way to remove those attributes from the imported data.

PS.: There are thousands of attributes, so I don't want to specify the attributes that need to be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove them using the "remove" filter in WEKA's Explorer.
Once the data has been loaded into WEKA:

1) Go to "Process" (1st main tab).

2) In "filter" area click "Choose" a filter.

3) Navigate through the tree to "filters" -> "unsupervised" -> "attribute" -> "Remove".

4) Once "Remove" filter has been chosen, click to "Remove" label next to "Choose" button, it will open a dialog.

5) Fill out the attributeIndices text field with the index/indices of the attributes to be removed, i.e. "1,4,10" or "1-3,7".

6) Click "OK" in the dialog and "Apply" button in the filter area of the main window.

That's all !!

Comment: It is almost the solution that I'm looking for. The main problem is the number of attributes, there are a thousand of them. I would like to know a solution where I don't need to specify the attributes.

Comment: you can specify a range, or you can parse the file finding which columns have missing values and get their indices to use them as a parameter to remove filter. It is quite easy to do using AWK (if you need some help, let me know)

Comment: Yes, I could parse the file. In truth, I could do everything else with a little piece of code. But I was wondering if there is a "lazier" way to achieve the same result. Anyway, I thank you for your help! I'll wait a little more for another suggestion, but if nobody does it, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.RemoveUseless might help